# Does Protobuf-net connect over Internet for performing some checks?

Tags: protobuf-net

We use the library protobuf-net in our project and based on a customer request we are trying to figure out If the library communicates over to Internet any time during the course of operations?

It will be helpful if someone can confirm this.

https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net

I have not tried to look into the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you just mean protobuf-net and not protobuf-net.Grpc, then: no, it doesn't reach out over the internet for anything, as far as I can think (and: I wrote it). If you *give it a `Stream` for deserialize/serialize that is connected to somewhere*, it read/write, but that's your code.